# ASP.NET MVC 3 Cache Duration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app hosted on IIS. This app is using MemoryCache to work with some data in memory to help minimize hits to my database. I would like this data to stay cached for up to a single day. In my code, I'm setting the following:

```
List<MyObject> myItems = GetMyItems();
CacheItemPolicy cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
cachePolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1440));
Cache.Set("myCacheKey", myItems, cachePolicy);
```

While my caching seems to be working. However, it does not seem to stay in the cache for the intended duration. Is there a setting I need to make in the web.config, if so, what setting? If not, is it an IIS setting that I need to set to enable a longer cache duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely lies in that your app pool is recycling after periods of non-use. When app pools are recycled, everything you had in memory is lost.

If you need a more durable cache, you will need to switch to something that is not hosted in process. There are a number of commercial and open-source caching services; I would recommend going with one of those.

Here are just a few cache solutions:

1. [SharedCache](http://sharedcache.codeplex.com/)
2. [AppFabric](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15848)
3. [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)
4. [MemCached.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/)

Amongst others.